# What's the different between these opencv libs that have the very similar name ? Which should I put into project libraries?

Tags: eclipse, opencv

I am on Linux(Ubuntu) with OpenCV 2.4 installed. I am try to use Eclipse to create an opencv project. When I build the project, I got `collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` error which I guess is caused by missing libs. Then I put libraries in this project, but I find every lib has three very similar brothers, like:

```
libopencv_highgui.so
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.0
```

So, which one should I add to project libraries? And what's the different between them?

Best Regards.

Comment: I suspect that the first two are symlinks to the third.  Try using `stat` to see if they are.

Comment: @Corbin I use `stat`, but can't find where the file links to. The three file all has a `LINKs: 1`.

Comment: Does it say "regular file" or "symbolic link" on the right-middle side?  They may actually be separate files.  What I'm thinking though is that it's the 2.4.0 version of the lib and thus each link is a more specific name of the library (so if you *had* to link to 2.4.0 and not 2.4.2 for example, you could).

Comment: @Corbin  YES. I are right, the first two are symbolic link but the third is a regular file. And which one should I add to project?

Comment: I've posted an answer summarizing our comments a bit and explaining how to decide which to link against.  Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libopencv_highgui.so` and `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4` are probably [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.0`.

Libraries frequently do this so that software that needs to link against specific versions can while keeping the generic library also exposed.

This is mainly useful when a program to be linked against a major or minor version of a library.  Consider if a legacy application needed to link against version 1.2 of `libopencv_highgui`.  The program couldn't link against `libopencv_highgui.so` because that's not guaranteed to be the correct version.  However, the program could link against `libopencv_highgui.so.1.2`.  libopencv_highgui.so.1.2 may be a symbolic link to libopencv_highgui.so.1.2.3, but that would be ok since the third number usually means a minor bug fix that won't break compatibility.

So this brings up which file you should link against.  This really depends.  Unless you need to depend on some bug or quirk of a specific minor revision, I would definitely avoid linking against the 2.4.0 one.  That ties your program specifically to version 2.4.0.  When 2.4.1 gets released (or trickles down your distro's package manager), it probably won't break your program.

If you link against `libopencv_highgui.so` and then 2.5 is installed as the main lib (and then libopencv_highgui.so links to libopencv_highgui.so.2.5.0), there is a chance that your program will not link correctly since the second number does sometimes mean compatibility changes.

So in short, if it's a personal project, just link to whatever you want.  libopencv_highgui.so is probably safe if it's personal.  If it's going to be distributed, figure out what versions of the library your code will link properly against and then use the vaguest one possible.  For example, if your code works with 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4, you should go ahead and link to `libopencv_highgui.so`.  If it only works specifically with 2.4.0, you should link with `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.0`.  If it will work with any sub revision of 2.4, you should go with libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.

Basically you have to make a choice about what you think will link properly on the most people's setups.

Comment: WOW, amazing typing speed. You explain this very clear, Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I make some mistake here. What I need is these libraries, But when I add them into project libraries. YOU SHOULD USE THESE NAMES, for the library I mentioned in the question, we should add `opencv_highgui` in to eclipse libraries dependency but `libopencv_highgui.so.2.4`. For the future use, I write these stuff [here](https://snipt.net/stevenYANG/opencv-library-nameadd-to-eclipse/).